# Reshape distance matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the shape of df1

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'From': ['A','B','C'],
    'To': ['X','Y','Z'],
    'Price': [1,2,3] 
})
```

What I am trying to do is reshape df1 to have the form of df2. The desired end result would be this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Location': ['A','X','B','Y','C','Z'],
    'Direction': ['Origin','Destination','Origin','Destination','Origin','Destination'],
    'Price': [1,1,2,2,3,3] 
})
```

I would like to achieve that with pandas stack(), pivot(), melt(), etc., but I cannot figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `rename` columns, then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df1.rename(columns={'From':'Origin','To':'Destination'})
         .set_index('Price')
         .rename_axis('Direction', axis=1)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='Location')
         .reindex(['Location','Direction','Price'], axis=1))
print (df)
  Location    Direction  Price
0        A       Origin      1
1        X  Destination      1
2        B       Origin      2
3        Y  Destination      2
4        C       Origin      3
5        Z  Destination      3
```

If order is not important:

```
df2 = (df1.rename(columns={'From':'Origin','To':'Destination'})
          .melt('Price',var_name='Direction',value_name='Location')
          .reindex(['Location','Direction','Price'], axis=1)
         )
print (df2)
  Location    Direction  Price
0        A       Origin      1
1        B       Origin      2
2        C       Origin      3
3        X  Destination      1
4        Y  Destination      2
5        Z  Destination      3
```